# Iframe Embed Links not Left Clickable in some Browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, embed

I'm trying to implement a simple html iframe embed that contains links to items in our catalog. The embed element shows up fine on the site, and the side buttons to click through the titles works fine. However the links to the items themselves do not work on left click. When you hover the correct links will show up on the bottom left side of the page, and you can right click -> open in new tab. Nothing happens at all when left clicked. The element works just as expected in Firefox, the problem occurs in Chrome and Edge. I cannot change the code within the contents of the iframe, I am just trying to get the embed working. This is the bit of html I used.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://wal.search.owwl.org/API/SearchAPI?method=getCollectionSpotlight&amp;id=8" style="border:none;" height="300" width="900"></iframe>
<body>
<html
```

I tried adding a few snippets to the iframe people said could help such as

```
target="_parent"
sandbox="allow-popups"
```

but they didn't work, or I didn't implement them properly. I'm not much of a coder, just kinda assigned to this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.